# I am new to php. I am getting this error and don't know how to correct it. Can anyone help me with this?

Tags: php, html

Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Missing Properties
The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFUXd.png)

Comment: It's not clear what the image has to do with the text of the question, and both are making it unclear what you're actually asking.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a php thing. It's a html metadata thing.

Your `.html` / `.php` file must look like this..

**Example:**

```
<html prefix="og: https://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>Your website title</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Your website title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.your-url.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.your-url.com/image.jpg" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="your_facebook_app_id" />
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Read here for more information: https://ogp.me/